# Função para botão adicionar e remover - para clonar formulario

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde, tenho a seguinte questão: 
tenho um formulário de ficha de treino, com o seguintes Campos em dropdown:

GRUPO  EXERCÍCIO SERIE REPETIÇÃO CARGA PAUSA

e gostaria de ter a opção de repetir o campo, ficando assim:

GRUPO EXERCÍCIO SERIE REPETIÇÃO CARGA PAUSA [BOTÃO ADICIONAR] [BOTÃO REMOVER]

e quando clicasse no botão, aparecesse novamente os mesmos campos, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Grata.[novata]

Comment: Podes editar a tua pergunta para conter algum código?

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer como está descrito abaixo. Porém terá de tratar de cuidar dos ids duplicados na hora do submit do formulário. Pode tratar no javascript para alterar o id do duplicado. Poderia me explicar o porque você quer essa duplicação? Talvez eu possa lhe dar uma solução melhor do que essa de duplicação

```js
var newid = 1;
function adicionaForm() {
  var formulario = document.getElementById("form")
  var cln = formulario.cloneNode(true);
  cln.id = cln.id+newid;
  document.getElementById("div").append(cln);
  newid = newid+1;
}

function removerForm(){
document.getElementById("div").lastChild.remove();

}
```

```css
#div form label{
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
}

#div form input{
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
width:100%;
}
#div form{
margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <form id="form">
    <label>Grupo</label>
    <input type="text"><br/>
    <label>Exercício</label>
    <input type="text"><br/>
    <label>Série</label>
    <input type="text"><br/>
    <label>Repetição</label>
    <input type="text"><br/>
    <label>Carga</label>
    <input type="text"><br/>
    <label>Pausa</label>
    <input type="text"><br/>
  </form>
</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="adicionaForm()" id="adicionar">Adicionar Exercício</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="removerForm()" id="adicionar">Remover Exercício</button>
```

Comment: preciso que duplique para que o professor possa adicionar exercicios à ficha do aluno, e caso ele queira remover o exercicio para atualizar o treino =D

Comment: Da uma olhada agora, fiz umas alterações vê se fica bom assim

Comment: Lucas, muitíssimo obrigada! me ajudou muito!!! Valew!!!

Comment: Se puder marca como resposta